# How can I use the same window to execute every query in SQL Server 2012? Reuse the same window don't update data

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012, and I am testing so the data is changing when I debug my application which does INSERT in tables.

I found that if I have done a query to a table, and then the data changes in this table, and I want to see the change using "select 1000 lines" by right clicking on the table, the changes are not shown but only old data, because by default SQL Server 2012 uses the same query window opened previously. I must close the query window and query again, then the change appears.

When I use Oracle Developer, by default it only creates one query window to execute every query even it's the same table, so the changes of data can be shown every time I do a query. And there is a Pin bottom to lock current query window, so I can open new window if I want to. It is good, and now in SQL Server it is bad.

So, I want to ask:

- Is there an option to force only one query window at the same time?
  Or,
- Is there an option to close the query window after I complete a query?

I have searched a lot and no result. I just don't want to close the query every time I change data. It causes many confusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just add select statement in the end of your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hit refresh button or press `F5` to refresh the result set. BTW, SQL Server 2012 (at least) does open new window every time you select top 1000 by right clicking on the table. However, SQL Server open same window when you use "`Edit TOP 200 rows`"

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have just noticed, if we do SELECT, we have `F5` or `Refresh`. If we do EDIT, we can right-click on the editor area and "Execute query", which act like `F5`.